# Using & with string class objects in c++

Tags: c++

As far as my knowledge in c++, the `&` character can act as an address of operator(finding the address of a variable in memory) or as a bitwise AND operator or declaring references.

However if I run this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "Stackoverflow";
    cout<<&s[0]<<endl<<&s[1]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
Stackoverflow
tackoverflow
```

I expected it to print the addresses of the first 2 characters of the string, however, I got the string itself starting from a different index. How does it work?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2 note overload (2).

Comment: You get a pointer to a character, of type `char*`, for which there is an overload to print it as a null-terminated string.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/TGx33qbWa

Comment: `cout<<static_cast<void*>(&s[0])<<endl<<static_cast<void*>(&s[1])<<endl;`